# WooCommerce webite not displaying properly on any iOS devices

Tags: php, ios, woocommerce

I’ve developed a responsive website with marketplace functionalities in woocommerce and it worked perfectly fine until a couple of days ago.

It works on desktop and android devices except for all iOS devices where it shows a white screen with a fine colorful line at the top. When i try to test it in chrome with iPhone sizes it works fine.

I’ve spent 3 days searching for a solution but i just can’t find anyone with the same problem.

SCREENSHOTS:  [iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Y7M.jpg) and [macbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0888L.png)

ALSO [this is the website](http://pachetdelamama.ro)

It doesn't have any errors.

I’ve uninstalled all the plug-ins i didn’t need in case one of those were causing this problem.

I’ve tried using a health plug-in but it didn’t find any problem related to this.

Comment: Please share screenshot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Y7M.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/0888L.png

Comment: Please EDIT your question and add this screenshot to it. Please avoid posting question's details as comment to your own question. See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of my plugins were automatically adding the following CSS to the website:

```
.site {
overflow-y: -webkit-paged-y;
```

}

I just changed it to override that

> .site {
>       overflow-y: visible !important;
>   }